# Date format issue in Task Parallel Library

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

if i call this method sequentiality,

```
object[] ab = GetSomething(myObject);
```

i get the date time format like this, which is ok

[image]

know if i use tpl, to invoke this method

```
Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetSomething(myObject));
Task t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetSomeOtherthing(myObject));
Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
```

I get this format with AM/PM which is causing conversion to fail, saying invalid datetime format, is there a way to change the datetime formart like the sequential method.

[image]

How i am converting the string to datetime

```
Search.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(myObject.ToDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: What is the code for `GetSomething` that is setting the `Date`?

Comment: @NeilKnight iam using Convert.ToDateTime (myObject.ToDate) is in string format

Comment: The next question is what is `ToDate` on `myObject`? A property? How is it implemented? What is its data type?

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer yes A property of type string.

Comment: From the comments that myself and @Jesse C. Slicer have asked, it looks like you need to specify a format in your `ToDate` string.

Comment: Agreed. Try `Convert.ToDateTime(myObject.ToDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` and see what that gets you.

Comment: @NeilKnight i dont know why but when i run the method without tpl it works perfect, but when i run it on tpl it breaks, why does it change the date formart. DateTime.ParseExact(myObject.ToDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", null); I have tried the above but same issue

Comment: @NeilKnight, no luck with CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.

Comment: It's either an artifact of the debugger or you're changing the CultureInfo of a Thread somewhere.

Comment: @HenkHolterman no changes to the CultureInfo of a Thread but what is the default datetime format of the thread when it is created

Comment: Can you post a sample program that exposes this problem? And you could add a line that outputs the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` directly before the conversion. And example of the string you're trying to parse wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: I would rule out the debugger first. And since it looks like `Search.Date` is a DateTime we may have a non-problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always explicitly specify a culture when converting from/to string.

In your case it's likely that the threadpool threads have a different CurrentCulture from what you're expecting.

Comment: Is there a way to change the threadpool threads CurrentCulture to a specific one.

Comment: @AI25 I'd avoid that. `DateTime.Parse` and similar functions have a parameter that takes a culture. Use that one.

Comment: What if you use a library that uses DateTime.Pars/DateTime.ToString without passing a specific CultureInfo... I think you need to set the CurrentCulture on the Thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the culture of the thread, then create your own task scheduler that knows the application culture. The scheduler can adjust the culture before executing the task.

This is a sample scheduler...

```
class LocalizedTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler
{
    public CultureInfo Culture { get; set; }
    public CultureInfo UICulture { get; set; }

    #region Overrides of TaskScheduler

    protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
    {
        //Queue the task in the thread pool
        ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
        {
            //Adjust the thread culture
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = this.Culture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = this.UICulture;
            //Execute the task
            TryExecuteTask(task);
       }, null);
    }

    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
    {
        if (taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // Try to run the task. 
        return base.TryExecuteTask(task);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
    {
        //We have no queue
        return Enumerable.Empty<Task>();
    }

    #endregion
}
```